# Tracking-URL : N/A , RPC Port : -1

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

Is this ok or something I should fix?

```
ubuntu@anmol-vm1-new:~$ yarn application -status application_1448835095947_0394
15/12/05 19:37:56 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.0.1.190:8032
15/12/05 19:37:56 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/12/05 19:37:57 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at /10.0.1.190:10200
Application Report : 
    Application-Id : application_1448835095947_0394
    Application-Name : OrderedWordCountSession
    Application-Type : TEZ
    User : ubuntu
    Queue : default
    Start-Time : 1449343145138
    Finish-Time : 0
    Progress : 0%
    State : ACCEPTED
    Final-State : UNDEFINED
    Tracking-URL : N/A
    RPC Port : -1
    AM Host : N/A
    Diagnostics :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't have to fix anything.

The `State` of your application is `ACCEPTED` and `Final-State` is `UNDEFINED`. It means, your application just got accepted and has not started `RUNNING`. Also you can see that `Progress` is `0%` and `Finish-Time` is `0`.

Once it enters into `RUNNING` state, you should be able to see both `Tracking-URL` and `RPC Port`.

Your application can go through `NEW`, `NEW_SAVING`, `SUBMITTED`, `ACCEPTED`, `RUNNING`, `FINISHED`, `FAILED` and `KILLED` states. You will NOT see the `Tracking-URL` (it will be **N/A**) and `RPC Port` (it will be **-1**), when the application is in `NEW`, `NEW_SAVING`, `SUBMITTED` and `ACCEPTED` states. For rest of the states you should get the proper `Tracking-URL` and `RPC Port`.

I have also observed one more thing. After an application is `FINISHED` (either `FAILED` or `SUCCEEDED`) or `KILLED`, if you re-start your YARN services and then get the status of your application, then you will see `RPC Port` as `-1`. But, you should still see a proper `Tracking-URL`.

For e.g.

`Tracking-URL : http://myhost.corp.myorg.com:19888/jobhistory/job/job_1449030777768_0003`.